# What do you recommend to do MySQL queries on PHP array without MySQL connection (interpreter)?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, interpreter

The idea is this:

```
<?php
// table definition as a php array
$array = array(
  array( "code" => 0, "value" => 1 ), // => row1
  array( "code" => 1, "value" => 2 ),// => row2
  array( "code" => 2, "value" => 345 ),// => row3
  array( "code" => 234, "value" => 231 ),// => row4
  array( "code" => 23, "value" => 34 ),// => row5
  array( "code" => 3, "value" => 5465 ),// => row6
  array( "code" => 4, "value" => 34 ) // => row7
);
?>
```

What I need to do is to interpret simply MySQL queries with PHP arrays like:

```
SELECT * FROM ($array) WHERE code > 23 AND value = 231
```

What ideas you have?
1. Tools you know.
2. Plugins.
3. MySQL Parsers.
4. Best way.

Comment: MySQL is a DBMS. So you better do a array search using PHP.

Comment: Why would you need this? MySQL own command interpreter is *very* complex thing, written using Bison parser library (http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) - I doubt you will be able to do something similar in PHP

Comment: Have you wrote something yet ? Coding a full MySQL queries interpreter is something quite huge, and I don't think this is your purpose here.

Comment: I need to do this, because I have a queries "CACHED" on PHP arrays, when the application will load again, the queries will be "EXECUTED" using this with the serialized data and not re-executing the query, do you understand?

Comment: Why not make it a database? One possibility is to use SQLite.

Comment: If you don't need anything fancy, writing your own parser for theese simple expressions should not be that hard.

Comment: I need to do simple queries Like a < b, a =b, (a> c and d < h)

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to execute queries against a real database first and then cache only query results? You may use some kind of dictionary - with key being the query text and value being the data array returned from DB

Comment: If your problem can only be solved by writing an SQL parser, then your problem arises from a bad decision made earlier. Fix that decision. 

Also, you don't need to write a query cache yourself, MySQL folks did a [pretty good job](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) on that theirselves.

Perhaps you want to explain better what problem you're trying to solve with this "caching".

Comment: You should be caching the query results, not the actual queries.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a MySQL interpreter. The PHP MySQL extensions connect to a database, that is totally independent of PHP. SQL is processed there, not inside PHP - the PHP extension just transports it from your code to the database and the results and status back.

You might want to look at the PHP extension `SQLite`, that does a similar job and works on a file in your webspace. For many jobs it can be used as a replacement for MySQL for small datasets - since you have your dataset in PHP code, it is assured to be small.

`SQLite` is bundled with most PHP installations.

**Edit**

After reading, that you want to use this for MySQL query caching, please read up on MySQL's query cache first. It does what you want transparently.

If this doesn't work for you, you might want to check your business logic: Chances are, that you want to cache outdated result sets. If this turrns out to be a corner case where the MySQL query cache fails (these do exist), you might want to simply generate a hash of the SQL and use either `memcached` or an array to connect the SQL hash with the result set - no need to parse the SQL.

Comment: Have you read the questions and comments? He is building a query cache. Using SQLite to cache MySQL data is not going to help here, if anywhere. If it's really only caching it's about, then OP could take a look at [memcached](http://memcached.org/).

Comment: @CodeCaster you might notice from the timestamps, that the OP added the info about building a cache only AFTER I answered. After reading the comments, I added an edit to my answer, even vefore you commented and downvoted. **I do not have posession of a time machine.**

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that attaching an SQL syntax to array access is weird.

Such a "caching" in PHP arrays just makes no sense.
If your data is limited to such a little number of rows, there is no point in caching at all.
And otherwise your cache will crash the server.